# Implication of logarithmic integration for validity of ODE solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For a lot of ODE there are formulas which use the natural log trick to derive the solution like $y'(x) = xy \rightarrow y = e^{\int_{1}^{x}tdt}$, but the problem is that by definition $\ln$ is defined as $\int_{1}^{t}\tfrac{1}{u}du.$ So if your solution exists at negative values $<0$, then I don't understand how its existence could be justified when you must have taken the natural log of negative numbers to obtain it. Otherwise, is there a way the solution can be integrated from arbitrary bounds? But then if you do you no longer have the definition of $\ln.$ What fixes this?

Comment: "$\ln$ is defined as $\int_1^t \ln(u)\mathrm{d}u$". What??

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: There is an abuse of notation that happens, where we write $\ln(x)$ instead of $\ln(|x|)$, which (in the most common presentation) winds up being absorbed into a constant of integration that is "really" positive (since it is $e^c$) being allowed to be negative.

Comment: For an example with $y'=ty$, you write $z'=t$ where $z=\ln(|y|)$, now $z(t)-z(s)=\int_s^t r dr = \frac{t^2-s^2}{2}=\ln(|y(t)|)-\ln(|y(s)|)$, now you fix $s,t,y(s)$ and solve for $y(t)$ in terms of them. You get $|y(t)|=|y(s)| e^{\frac{t^2-s^2}{2}}$ and now for continuity, you must have that $y(t)$ and $y(s)$ have the same sign, so $y(t)=y(s) e^{\frac{t^2-s^2}{2}}$ irrespective of whether $y(s)$ is positive or negative. You see immediately that if you forget about the absolute values then this derivation doesn't make sense when $y(s)<0$.

Comment: @CheeseMongoose You're defining the natural logarithm in terms of its own integral? EDIT: Ok it's fixed now. It's easier to define $\ln$ as the inverse of $\exp$.

Comment: @Ian okay so in practice the result is an absolute value, and you just choose the plus or minus component and analyze those independently? Why do they need to have the same sign to be continuous?

Comment: As another example, consider just $y'=y$. Say $y(0)>0$. Then $\frac{d}{dt} \ln(y)=1$ so $\ln(y)=t+C_1$ so $y=e^t e^{C_1}$. Now say $y(0)<0$. Now it makes no sense to describe the dynamics of $\ln(y)$, you should look at $\ln(-y)$. Then $\ln(-y)=t+{C_1}$ so $-y=e^t e^{C_1}$ so $y=-e^t e^{C_1}$. The "cheat" that we use is to identify $+e^{C_1}$ and $-e^{C_1}$, together, as both being a new constant of integration $C_2$ that can have either sign.

Comment: An alternate way to look at it is to first focus on $y(0)>0$ and then notice that everything propagates through nicely when you multiply everything by $-1$ (this is a consequence of linearity of the equation).